# directive on child of components

Tags: vue.js, directive

In this case the directive *v-console* is applied to the entire *div* of *compo1*.

But would like to apply the directive only to the *input*. So the console.log should output the input field.

what's the proper way to do it ?

```html
<div id="app">
    <compo1 v-console>John</compo1>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('compo1', {
    template: '<div>Hello <slot></slot><input type="text" name="test" value="This is my value"></div>'
});

Vue.directive('console', {
    inserted: function (el) {
        console.log(el);
    }
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: Maybe directive should be first? Also, try to include directives and components directly to avoid the usage of a global declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <compo1 v-console><div slot>John</div></compo1>
</div>
```

Also, not wrapped by an element text, is da bad practice.